# Facebook graph API: mark message as read

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I get message conversations via Facebook graph API which looks like:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/' + id + '/messages?fields=message
```

and I want to mark as read the message but I can't find how to in documents.

please, can someone point me to some examples?

Comment: I'm having the issue right now. Even if I use mark_seen as sender_action, the unread_count of that specific thread doesn't seem to change.

Answer (score 0):

You only have read access to the Inbox via the API. So this is not currently possible.

Comment: But i can send messages ... why i can not mark message as read ?

Comment: Are you writing a bot?

Comment: He is right, it is not possible, see the full documentation : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.10/message or https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.10/conversation

Comment: You can do a POST to a conversation-id, which will post a message. You can’t however manage individual messages from a conversation. If you’re writing a bot, maybe Siddhesh answer will help you, but that **only shows a seen message on the chat mini window, not on your Page**

Answer (score 0):

You can set typing indicators or send read receipts using the API, to let users know you are processing their request.

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
"recipient":{
"id":"<PSID>"
},
  "sender_action":"typing_on"
}' "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages?access_token=<PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN>"
```

Comment: could u provide me with link to facebook graph api to test

Comment: Here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference/sender-actions

Answer (score 0):

Check below.

sender action = mark_seen..
I am using it and its working fine..

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages/sender-actions/

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
"recipient":{
"id":"<PSID>"
},
"sender_action":"mark_seen"
}' "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages?access_token=
<PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN>"
```